# HP DL380p 25 sff sas expander speed

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sas

on the HP DL380p 25 disk sff version whats the sff backplane and expander speed?
Reading the specs i can assume its 12g so with a controller like p830 it should be able to work at full speed.

anyone has experience with the above setup ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an expander, so it's oversubscribed.

Your individual disk link speeds are going to be 6Gbps.
There's no advantage to using a P830 controller over the embedded P420i controller in that system.

Comment: so i guess the only way to fully utilize 12g disks on gen8 is with an enclosure like d3700 ?

Comment: What is your goal? Why does the disk link speed important to you?

Comment: I want to create a vmware storage. I wss thinking of around 20 sas ssd disks in a raid 10 array for vms storage.

Comment: VMware storage performance won't be sequential to a point where the SAS link speed or throughput matter.

Comment: i see , thx for your time